# gulp serve error

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, nodejs, gulp

When run gulp serve I am getting below error

[image]

I am using below packages
[image]

I found on internet that if you are using node 12 and gulp 3 then it will have above issue but I am having node 12 and gulp 4, still I am having error

Comment: Spfx only supports node 10 at the moment.

Comment: @GautamSheth what about gulp. Which Gulp version it supprt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the official document here:

[Set up your SharePoint Framework development environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)

Use Node.js v10.x.

Install Yeoman and gulp:

```
npm install -g yo gulp
```

Install Yeoman SharePoint generator:

```
npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
```